# Wrong Standard Deviation result in PHP

Tags: php, kohana, standard-deviation

I have a problem with calculating the standard deviation in php. But it's generating the wrong result.

e.g. I am getting as result for (4+4+4+4+4+4) = 1.40 instead of 0.

Please help.

```
function std_dev ($attr, $test1,$test2,$test3,$test4,$test5,$test6) {
    //$items = array($test1->$attr,$test2->$attr,$test3->$attr,$test4->$attr,$test5->$attr,$test6->$attr);
    $items[] = array();

    if (isset($test1) && $test1->$attr != 9 && $test1->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test1->$attr;
    }
    if (isset($test2) && $test2->$attr != 9  && $test2->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test2->$attr;
    }
    if (isset($test3) && $test3->$attr != 9 && $test3->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test3->$attr;
    }
    if (isset($test4) && $test4->$attr != 9 && $test4->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test4->$attr;
    }
    if (isset($test5) && $test5->$attr != 9 && $test5->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test5->$attr;
    }
    if (isset($test6) && $test6->$attr != 9 && $test6->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test6->$attr;
    }

    $sample_square[] = array();
    $item_count = count($items);
    for ($current = 1; $item_count > $current; ++$current) $sample_square[$current] = pow($items[$current], 2);

    $standard_deviation = sqrt(array_sum($sample_square) / $item_count - pow((array_sum($items) / $item_count), 2));

    return round($standard_deviation,2);

}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug your code?

Comment: none never learned it. I will try learning it after today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items = array();

$sample_square = array();
```

no `[]` when you define those variables as arrays.

```
for ($current = 0; $item_count > $current; ++$current)
```

start from **0** not **1** if you want to iterate over all the elements (otherwise you'll miss item at index 0)

---

Wondering what this is for...

```
if (isset($test1) && $test1->$attr != 9 && $test1->$attr != 0) {
    $items[] = $test1->$attr;
}
```

and how you pass input values to the function. This may also cause wrong result...

Comment: Removing the square brackets and changing the current to 0 worked. What's the reason that removing the square brackets gives a different result?

Comment: @Paolo I guess the if statement is just to insert all the values inside the array. It just checks if the values exist and they are different to 9 and 0. The values are just an attribute of the object testX and the function is receiving all the tests as parameters

Comment: When you write $a[]=xyz you push xyz at the end of the array $a. So as you write $a[] -as $a is not still defined- you are impliclitly defining it as an array. As you write $a[]=array() you are making $a an array and assigning as a first value (another) empty array.

Comment: @Alberto I guessed the same too. But as you write... it's a guess. Maybe the OP intended to do something different and here lies some unexpected behaviuors. I pointed my answer to what it seem to be 99% an error.

Comment: @Paolo Ahh I get it so using the brackets I am attaching an item to it. Thanks for explaining.